# Nuxt3 with VueUse Motion 'Cannot start nuxt: Package subpath './nuxt' is not defined by "exports"'

Tags: nuxtjs3, vueuse

I have been trying to use [VueUse Motion](https://motion.vueuse.org/nuxt.html) with Nuxt3. I have followed the documentation and installed `@vueuse/motio` and after I add `'@vueuse/motion/nuxt'` to my `nuxt.config.ts` file.
But when I wanted to run dev server, it yields this error:

`Cannot start nuxt:  Package subpath './nuxt' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\orhan\Desktop\p3\node_modules\@vueuse\motion\package.json`
[image]

**Here is my modules in `nuxt.config.ts`**

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@vueuse/nuxt',
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    '@vueuse/motion/nuxt',
  ],
```

**My `package.json` file:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/json": "^2.1.116",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "@vueuse/motion": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.11",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.13",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "unplugin-icons": "^0.14.11",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.22.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.2",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^9.3.0",
    "daisyui": "^2.31.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

The nuxt version you are using (`3.0.0-rc.11`) has compatibility issues with `@vueuse/motion@2.0.0-beta.12`.

### Solution:

In your `package.json`, just try changing `"@vueuse/motion": "^2.0.0-beta.12"` to `"@vueuse/motion": "^2.0.0-beta.23"`.

Then run `pnpm install` and `pnpm dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade `@vueuse/motion` to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried updating "@vueuse/motion": "^2.0.0-beta.12" to "@vueuse/motion": "^2.0.0-beta.23" then installed the dependencies, still no luck.

> ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot set properties of undefined
> (setting 'motion')
> 10:51:00
>
> at setup
> (D:/Users/markj/Desktop/COLLAVE/brandedspaces-ph/node_modules/.pnpm/@vueuse+motion@2.0.0-beta.23/node_modules/@vueuse/motion/dist/nuxt.cjs:16:45)   at normalizedModule
> (D:/Users/markj/Desktop/COLLAVE/brandedspaces-ph/node_modules/.pnpm/@nuxt+kit@3.2.3/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:167:29)
> at async installModule
> (/D:/Users/markj/Desktop/COLLAVE/brandedspaces-ph/node_modules/.pnpm/@nuxt+kit@3.2.3/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:435:15)
> at async initNuxt
> (/D:/Users/markj/Desktop/COLLAVE/brandedspaces-ph/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxt@3.2.3/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2256:7)
> at async load
> (/D:/Users/markj/Desktop/COLLAVE/brandedspaces-ph/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxi@3.2.3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6810:9)
> at async Object.invoke
> (/D:/Users/markj/Desktop/COLLAVE/brandedspaces-ph/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxi@3.2.3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6871:5)
> at async _main
> (/D:/Users/markj/Desktop/COLLAVE/brandedspaces-ph/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxi@3.2.3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:50:20)